# Heroku logs "meteor not found"

Tags: meteor, heroku

Hi I am trying to deploy my meteorJS app to heroku, my site is showing this, how can I fix this?:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

https://mkred.herokuapp.com/

I am getting this error in my heroku logs:

```
2017-05-19T14:14:03.499437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-05-19T14:14:06.322560+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:06.322581+00:00 app[web.1]: > mkred@ start /app
2017-05-19T14:14:06.322582+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2017-05-19T14:14:06.322582+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:06.332513+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2017-05-19T14:14:06.350330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-19T14:14:06.338381+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:06.350859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-19T14:14:06.351084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-19T14:14:06.351286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-19T14:14:06.351500+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-05-19T14:14:06.351682+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-19T14:14:06.351907+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-05-19T14:14:06.352262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-05-19T14:14:06.352444+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mkred@ start: `meteor run`
2017-05-19T14:14:06.352626+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-05-19T14:14:06.352786+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-19T14:14:06.352949+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mkred@ start script 'meteor run'.
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mkred package,
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353351+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353481+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353752+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-19T14:14:06.353885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mkred
2017-05-19T14:14:06.354023+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-19T14:14:06.354154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mkred
2017-05-19T14:14:06.354283+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-19T14:14:06.362397+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:06.362724+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-19T14:14:06.362875+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-19T14:14:06.458295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-19T14:14:06.477342+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-19T14:14:06.478779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-19T14:14:10.559212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-05-19T14:14:16.452733+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:16.452750+00:00 app[web.1]: > mkred@ start /app
2017-05-19T14:14:16.452751+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2017-05-19T14:14:16.452751+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:16.509230+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2017-05-19T14:14:16.542185+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:16.607377+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-19T14:14:16.609274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-19T14:14:16.610648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-19T14:14:16.611286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-19T14:14:16.612308+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-05-19T14:14:16.614062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-19T14:14:16.615617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-05-19T14:14:16.620791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-05-19T14:14:16.621597+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mkred@ start: `meteor run`
2017-05-19T14:14:16.622556+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-05-19T14:14:16.623330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-19T14:14:16.625501+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-19T14:14:16.625097+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mkred@ start script 'meteor run'.
2017-05-19T14:14:16.626725+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mkred package,
2017-05-19T14:14:16.627246+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-19T14:14:16.627589+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-19T14:14:16.628014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2017-05-19T14:14:16.628637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-19T14:14:16.629392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mkred
2017-05-19T14:14:16.629812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-19T14:14:16.630466+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mkred
2017-05-19T14:14:16.632622+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-19T14:14:16.668367+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T14:14:16.669670+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-19T14:14:16.670806+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-19T14:14:16.808709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-19T14:14:16.795557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-19T14:14:17.872397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mkred.herokuapp.com request_id=71763503-4229-4282-9056-d24e0939cd91 fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-19T14:14:18.557778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mkred.herokuapp.com request_id=e5f63fdf-4f15-4da3-896b-95196a2241bc fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-19T14:17:14.776747+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mkred.herokuapp.com request_id=01c50fd0-2594-4ffe-a0ea-d5764ef00b92 fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-19T14:17:15.518706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mkred.herokuapp.com request_id=fad8ff27-813f-4d20-86f4-f16d35b3a34e fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Mohammads-MBP:mkred minimoe$
```

Comment: Have you installed a Heroku _buildpack_ for Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Direct not support by heroku.Node.js is Directly supported. Node.js use created Meteor Build Packs . You should use meteor buildpack [Meteor Buildpack](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) . And Heroku also availble Sandbox free Database. Thank You,Happy coding.